# An interesting case study regarding permission.

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

We have two users. Tom and Jim. System using krb5 and sldap.

```
Tom$ ssh machine1.somecompany.com
Password: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).

//////

Jim: ssh machine1.somecompany.com
Password:
sucesss

Jim@machine1$
Jim@machine1$ id Jim
uid=1178(Jim) gid=1178(Jim) groups=1178(Jim),0(wheel),60002(AAA),60006(BBB),60007(CCC)

Jim@machine1$ id Tom
uid=1178(Tom) gid=1178(Tom) groups=1178(Tom),0(wheel),60002(AAA)

//////
Tom$ ssh machine2.somecompany.com
Password: 
success!
Tom@machine2$ ssh machine1.somecompany.com
Password:
success!
Tom@machine1$
```

So Jim is able to directly ssh into machine 1; and jim belongs into two extra group BBB and CCC compare to Tom. 
Tom wasn't able to ssh into machine1 directly. However, tom can ssh into machine2 and then ssh into machine1.

What does this tells you about the system? If i manually add Tom in group BBB and CCC will tom be able to directly ssh into machine1? If i remove Jim from BBB and CCC will Jim be able to directly ssh into machine1?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information to know.

OpenSSH permits login restrictions (eg. "must use key-based authentication") to be set on a per-user, per-group, or per-remote-machine basis, as well as on other criteria that probably aren't relevant.  In order to find out, you'll need to look in the daemon's configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and possibly in the per-user configuration files (`~/.ssh/*`).

Comment: thanks. Mind if I ask which lines am I looking for in sshd_config. I look at the file and I didn't find anything regarding the permissions.

Comment: You're looking for any section starting with a `Match` line.  It's also possible that the restrictions are in the user's personal configuration; I'm not sure what you'd look for there.